# Threejs TrackBallControil top and bottom view not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a top,back,left,right,front,back views with my Trackballcontrol camera.
Before switching to another view, I call TrackBallControll reset method then I set my new position of my camera.
It works for all view except for top and back views. For this two last views, I cannot rotate my camera anymore.
This is my code:

```
function changeView(type) {
controls.reset();
if (type === 'front') {
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 500;
} else if (type == 'back') {
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = -500;
} else if (type == 'top') {
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 500;
    camera.position.z = 0;
} else if (type == 'bottom') {
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = -500;
    camera.position.z = 0;
} else if (type == 'right') {
    camera.position.x = 500;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 0;
} else if (type == 'left') {
    camera.position.x = -500;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 0;
}
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

}

Why it behaves like that?

Comment: This is caused by my camera up vector which is not correct for 'top' and 'bottom' view. I have to set it to vector3(0,0,1)